# Pass a list of lists of unquoted character parameters to an apply/map/pmap call

Tags: r, apply, lapply, purrr, tidyeval

I have created a function to do a certain type of analysis:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mediation)

causal_med_so <- function(predictor, mediator, outcome, data, ...){
  
  if(!missing(...)) {
    data <- {{data}} %>%
      dplyr::select({{predictor}}, {{mediator}}, {{outcome}}, ...) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ !is.na(.)))
    
    predictor <- enquo(predictor)
    mediator <- enquo(mediator)
    outcome <- enquo(outcome)
    
    med.form <- formula(paste0(
      quo_name(mediator), "~",
      paste0(
        quo_name(predictor), "+",
        paste0(c(...), collapse = "+"), 
        collapse = "+"
      )
    ))
    
    med.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(med.form), data = data)))
    
    out.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(outcome), "~",
                               paste0(
                                 quo_name(predictor), "+",
                                 quo_name(mediator), "+",
                                 paste0(c(...), collapse = "+"),
                                 collapse = "+"
                               )))
    
    out.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(out.form), data = data)))
    
    med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit,
                                  treat = quo_name(predictor),
                                  mediator = quo_name(mediator),
                                  boot=T, boot.ci.type = "bca")
    return(med.out)
  } else {
    data <- {{data}} %>%
      dplyr::select({{predictor}}, {{mediator}}, {{outcome}}) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ !is.na(.)))
    
    predictor <- enquo(predictor)
    mediator <- enquo(mediator)
    outcome <- enquo(outcome)
    
    med.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(mediator), "~", quo_name(predictor)))
    
    med.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(med.form), data = data)))
    
    out.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(outcome), "~",
                               quo_name(predictor), "+", quo_name(mediator)))
    
    out.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(out.form), data = data)))
    
    med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit,
                                  treat = quo_name(predictor),
                                  mediator = quo_name(mediator),
                                  boot=T, boot.ci.type = "bca")
    return(med.out)
  }
}
```

The function appears to work as intended:

```
 causal_med_so(mpg, cyl, qsec, mtcars)
```

I would now like to use this function in an apply/map/pmap call to run many models at once in all possible combinations:

```
param_list <- list(
  predictor = c("mpg", "cyl"),
  mediator = c("drat", "disp", "wt", "cyl"),
  outcome = c("qsec", "gear", "carb", "hp"),
  data = c("mtcars")
) %>%
  cross()
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
lmap(param_list, causal_med_so)
lapply(param_list, causal_med_so)
```

But I am encountering some error messages that suggest the list elements are being treated as characters. I have tried several combinations of `noquote()`, `syms()`, `!!!syms()` but can't quite seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are strings, it is better convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) (For testing, used only the first two rows of 'param_dat' (changed `cross` to `cross_df` so as to return a `tibble`)

```
causal_med_so <- function(predictor, mediator, outcome, data, ...){
  predictor <- rlang::ensym(predictor)
  mediator <- rlang::ensym(mediator)
  outcome <- rlang::ensym(outcome)
 
 
 if(!missing(...)) {
     data <- get(data, envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
       dplyr::select(!!predictor, !!mediator, !!outcome, ...) %>% 
       dplyr::filter(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ !is.na(.)))
    
     predictor <- enquo(predictor)
     mediator <- enquo(mediator)
     outcome <- enquo(outcome)
    
     med.form <- formula(paste0(
       quo_name(mediator), "~",
       paste0(
         quo_name(predictor), "+",
         paste0(c(...), collapse = "+"), 
         collapse = "+"
       )
     ))
    
     med.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(med.form), data = data)))
    
     out.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(outcome), "~",
                                paste0(
                                  quo_name(predictor), "+",
                                  quo_name(mediator), "+",
                                  paste0(c(...), collapse = "+"),
                                  collapse = "+"
                                )))
    
     out.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(out.form), data = data)))
    
     med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit,
                                   treat = quo_name(predictor),
                                   mediator = quo_name(mediator),
                                   boot=T, boot.ci.type = "bca")
     return(med.out)
   } else {
 
    data <- get(data, envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
      dplyr::select(!!predictor, !!mediator, !!outcome) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~ !is.na(.)))
    
    
    
  med.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(mediator), "~", quo_name(predictor)))
  
  med.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(med.form), data = data)))
  
  out.form <- formula(paste0(quo_name(outcome), "~",
                             quo_name(predictor), "+", quo_name(mediator)))
  
  out.fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(out.form), data = data)))
  
  med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit,
                                treat = quo_name(predictor),
                                mediator = quo_name(mediator),
                                boot=T, boot.ci.type = "bca")
  return(med.out)
  }
  
  


}
```

-testing

```
param_dat <- list(
  predictor = c("mpg", "cyl"),
  mediator = c("drat", "disp", "wt", "cyl"),
  outcome = c("qsec", "gear", "carb", "hp"),
  data = c("mtcars")
)    %>% cross_df

out <- param_dat %>%
        slice_head(n = 2)%>%
     pmap(., causal_med_so)
Running nonparametric bootstrap

Running nonparametric bootstrap
```

-output

```
> str(out)
List of 2
 $ :List of 56
  ..$ d0           : num -0.0731
  ..$ d1           : num -0.0731
  ..$ d0.ci        : Named num [1:2] -0.1545 0.0325
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "3.053716%" "97.96547%"
  ..$ d1.ci        : Named num [1:2] -0.1545 0.0325
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "3.053716%" "97.96547%"
  ..$ d0.p         : num 0.158
  ..$ d1.p         : num 0.158
  ..$ d0.sims      : num [1:1000, 1] -0.0181 -0.0445 -0.0792 -0.1008 -0.088 ...
  ..$ d1.sims      : num [1:1000, 1] -0.0181 -0.0445 -0.0792 -0.1008 -0.088 ...
  ..$ z0           : num 0.197
  ..$ z1           : num 0.197
  ..$ z0.ci        : Named num [1:2] 0.0461 0.3122
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "1.787667%" "96.56288%"
  ..$ z1.ci        : Named num [1:2] 0.0461 0.3122
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "1.787667%" "96.56288%"
...
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! FYI the optional function parameters (...) are for possible additional covariates for adjustment (not all models will be adjusted). The idea here is to get the various model outputs in an object and extract/organize relevant parameters for tabular or file output. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the name of the dataset so it's clear which dataset was used in a particular model call?

Comment: @RaoulDuke can you post as a new question thanks

Comment: Thanks @akrun, posted as a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68990144/5745045